# Regex extract word from string

Tags: regex, logstash-grok

I want to filter the following word `APPLE` from this string:

```
"[BANANA => APPLE]"
```

I tried to do that with the RegEx `(?<=\> ).+?(?=])` but that doesn't solve my problem.

**EDIT:** I am trying this in Grok Debugger.
`%{TO:client}`.

```
TO (?<=\> ).+?(?=])
```

but displaying to me no matches.

Comment: How does this not work?

Comment: Try `=>\s*(?<client>[^\]]+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Grok uses an Oniguruma regex engine](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_regular_expressions), and fields are usually created with the help of named groups:

> you can use the Oniguruma syntax for named capture which will let you match a piece of text and save it as a field

You should use a named capturing group with a pattern like

```
=>\s*(?<client>[^\]]+)
```

It will match `=>`, 0+ whitespaces, and then will capture into Group "client" (the `client` field will then get created) one or more chars other than `]`.

Comment: I really liked your answer, Wiktor!

Comment: I have another question: How do I filter "Apple" From: [07/08/2018 | 16:40:05] | [Apple -> Orange]

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for? Just matching everything between `=>` and `]`

```
=> (.+?)\]
```

Your word will be in the first group. Of course there is still space to improve it with lookaheads etc.

I recommend to use https://regex101.com/ to debug and verify your regexps.

Comment: I cant handle groups in the Grok Debugger I think.

Comment: Ran, if your tool doesn't support groups that it DEFINITIVELY doesn't support lookarounds and more advanced regexp stuff.
Then preprocess your text in Python\JS script before you pass the data to your tool.